# Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Core RC2: loss of Custom Item Templates

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-templates, .net-core-rc2

I use Visual Studio 2015 update 2 Community Edition.

With Visual Studio DotNetCore RC1 tools I had my custom Item Template under DNX section. I can't provide proving screenshot because I already moved to DotNetCore RC2 Tools Preview 1. With the last set of tools I lost my Item Template.

[image]

I tried to change ProjectType and ProjectSubType from DNX to CSharp/Web, tried to put component in different places with no success.

The last .vstemplate file has the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>ReactComponent</DefaultName>
    <Name>ReactComponent</Name>
    <Description>ReactComponent</Description>
    <TemplateID>Chandrush.ReactComponent</TemplateID>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>Web</ProjectSubType>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$\$fileinputname$.tsx" ReplaceParameters="true">ReactComponent.tsx</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$\package.json" ReplaceParameters="true">package.json</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$\$fileinputname$.scss" ReplaceParameters="true">ComponentStyle.scss</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Do anybody know the solution, to get custom Item Templates back to VS2015u2 with .NetCore RC2 preview1 tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed for me.

Regarding your .vstemplate file, you must have to change these properties :

```
<ProjectType>DNX</ProjectType>  
<TemplateGroupID>DotNetWeb</TemplateGroupID>
```

Regards,

Comment: Yes! It helps! Thank you!

Comment: It does not seems to be working in final NET Core. "DNX" keyword is obsolete now and i dont know what is replacement for final bits of NET Core?

Comment: This is what works for me: `<ProjectType>DNX</ProjectType>
    <TemplateGroupID>SharedDotNetAndDotNetWeb</TemplateGroupID>`

Comment: Thank you, `<TemplateGroupID>SharedDotNetAndDotNetWeb</TemplateGroupID>` works for VS 2015 Upd 3 + .NET Core 1.1

Comment: For VS2017 ASP .NET Core projects works `<ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType><TemplateGroupID>AspNetCore</TemplateGroupID>` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030522/what-settings-should-be-used-to-get-custom-itemtemplates-working-with-net-core/44233307#44233307)