# Custom project item template not visible in .net core web application project

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, project, visual-studio-templates

I have created a custom project item template for Visual Studio to use in web applications. The template adds .js .html and .css files with a given name and some predefined content. I placed the template (zip-file) into MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ItemTemplates forler.

In traditional ASP.NET web application I can use this template to add items to the project (Project(right click at any project folder)->Add->New item, and then select my template from the list). The template is shown under "Visual C#" category.

But when I switched to new ASP.NET Core web application, I can not see my template in the list anymore. Project(right click at the project wwwroot folder)->Add->New item... shows me completely different templates grouped into different categories, and there is no my custom template among them.

My first guess was that `<ProjectType>` value in my .vstemplate file is not correct. I tried to replace `CSharp` by `Web` -- no luck, the template is still not visible.

Can anybody help me with following:

1. How to create a custom project item template to use in ASP.NET Core web application client-side code folder?
2. Where to place it, so it is visible in VS?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I have found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457501/visual-studio-2015-asp-net-core-rc2-lost-of-item-templates)