# How do I register a custom Item Template for .NET Core 1.1 RTM with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

Using VS 2015 Update 3 and .NET Core 1.1 RTM I have exported a custom item template to make it easier for my team to create some required boilerplate.  The generated .vstemplate file looks like this:

```
    <VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
      <TemplateData>
        <DefaultName>Mercury Repository.cs</DefaultName>
        <Name>Mercury Repository</Name>
        <Description>New Mercury Repository inherits from DB Context, implements Mercury stack standards</Description>
        <ProjectType>DNX</ProjectType>
        <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
        <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
      </TemplateData>
      <TemplateContent>
        <References />
        <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">AgimsRepository.cs</ProjectItem>
      </TemplateContent>
    </VSTemplate>
```

When I place the zipped package in the appropriate folder *\Filesrv-agct\UserData\username\My Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ItemTemplates.NET Core* (this is the templates folder specified in my Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/General setting), Visual Studio does not pick it up.  I think that it is the *ProjectType* which has changed since earlier version, but I can't find any documentation on it have and I have tried all the following types:

- CSharp (appears for .NET 4.6 projects, but not .NET Core)
- DNX
- DNXCore
- DnxCore50
- dotnet

None of these work.  Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: I also tried running `devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates` as an administrator, but this had no effect, and from the documentation only re-registers built-in templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the solution in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457501/visual-studio-2015-asp-net-core-rc2-lost-of-item-templates).

What works for me in VS2015 Update 3 + .NET Core 1.1.0 RTM is:

```
<ProjectType>DNX</ProjectType
<TemplateGroupID>SharedDotNetAndDotNetWeb</TemplateGroupID>
```

Actual answer given to that question did not work for me but appears to have worked for .NET Core 1.0 RC2 Tools Preview 1 (and so possibly .NET Core 1.0 - I can't test it):

```
<ProjectType>DNX</ProjectType>  
<TemplateGroupID>DotNetWeb</TemplateGroupID>
```

I'd love to know who thought those up, why they needed to be changed between versions, etc.  Anyway, hope this saves someone the hours I've spent on it!